# does continuity of sample paths imply continuity of natural filtration?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space (not necessarily complete) and let $X = (X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ be a real-valued stochastic process defined on it.

In general, is it true that if $X(\omega)$ is cadlag (resp., caglad) for every $\omega$, then its natural filtration (or at least its $\mathbb{P}$-augmentation) is right-continuous (resp., left-continuous)?

If not, are there additional assumptions that make this claim true?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The situation is dissymetric.

**Right-continuity** Let $X_t=(t-1-\mathbf 1_A)^+$ where $A$ in $\mathcal F$ is such that $P(A)$ is neither $0$ nor $1$. Then $(X_t)$ is path continuous, $\mathcal F^X_t=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ for every $t\leqslant1$ and $\mathcal F^X_t=\sigma(A)$ for every $t\gt1$, hence $\mathcal F^X_{1+}\ne\mathcal F^X_1$.

**Left-continuity** If $(X_t)$ is left-continuous, then $X_t=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_{t-1/n}$ and, for every $n$, $X_{t-1/n}$ is $\mathcal F^X_{t-}$-measurable, hence $X_{t}$ is $\mathcal F^X_{t-}$-measurable and $\mathcal F^X_t=\mathcal F^X_{t-}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! in the first counterexample, even if $\mathbb{P}(A) \in \{0,1\}$, the filtration is not right-continuous. But if we take its completion under $\mathbb{P}$ then it becomes right-continuous because we add $A$ and $A^c$ to every $\mathcal{F}_t^X$. Am I right?

Comment: You are. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2):

Did already pointed out in his answer that path continuity is insufficient to ensure right-continuity of the natural filtration.

As for sufficient conditions to make the augmented natural filtration right-continuous, being a Feller process is sufficient. See Theorem I.47 of Protter's "Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations". Protter in fact just assumes that the process is Markov, but I'm not sure if this is actually sufficient, his proof seems to use an earlier result which requires the Feller property.

This in particular implies that the augmented natural filtration of a Levy process is right-continuous. Protter also gives a proof of this claim separately using a different proof, see Theorem I.31 of the same book.